# double loop output into one matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I`ve got the following file with 10 rows and 13 columns (as an example, the real file is much bigger):

```
ID1 A B C D E F G H A B C D
ID2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
ID3 A B 1 2 C 1 2 D F R T G
...
```

I need to create a new matrix, where the input file`s 8-13 columns are placed in the every 4th column (there is also a condition, but that works fine; the issue is that the loop overwrites the output). Here is the script with loops:

```
data=read.table("input file", h=T)
out=matrix("NA",10,12)
for(i in c(1:10)){
for(k in seq(8,13,2){
for(s in seq(1,12,4){
for(q in seq(2,12,4){
out[i,s]=data[i,k]
out[i,q]=data[i,k+1]}}}}
```

Unfortunately, the loop overwrites the data and the output matrix (named "out" only has the last columns). I`d be very grateful for any suggestions on how to overcome this. I'm happy to try out vectors as loops perhaps not the best solution for this.

Many thanks!

Comment: For clarity, can you put the desired output for say just the first row or two?

Comment: yes, sorry. Here is the desired output for the first 3 rows of the input file:          first row: G H NA NA A B NA NA C D NA NA                                                                           second row: 7 8 NA NA 9 10 NA NA 11 12 NA NA                                                              third row: 2 D NA NA F R NA NA T G NA NA       (apologies for poor formatting)

Comment: @Tati - Please edit your post to include that information. Comments are hard to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want data[, 8] in out[, 1], data[, 9] in out[, 2], data[, 10] in out[, 5], etc.

This should do it

```
out <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(data), ncol = 12)
out[, sort(c(seq(1,9,4), seq(2,10,4)))] <- data[, seq(8, 13)]
```

Comment: Yes, you understand me correctly. Thank you so much! I apologize for the bad editing. Today is my first day of using this site. Many thanks for your help once again!

Comment: @Tati No problem. Don't forget to mark an answer as correct for future questioners.